# Play! Framework 2.4.x - Force creation of ebean configurations

Tags: playframework, ebean

I'm currently working on a Play! project, version 2.4.x for Java.

I've created an `Entity` in the folder `models` called User. This is the code for **User.php**:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;


@Entity
public class User extends Model{

    @Id
    public String Id;
    protected String name;
    protected String password;
    protected String email;

    /* -- getters and setters --*/
 }
```

This is the content of **application.conf**:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.username=sa
db.default.password=""
ebeans.default="models.*"
```

As you can see is a pretty standard configuration, I've just decommented the lines related to db options, I'm using ebeans as ORM.

The problem is that Play doesn't generate the evolutions files. For other projects I've worked on I've seen that, when I add an Entity or I modify a field in an entity I've created, the framework understand that I've made an edit so rigenerates the database and update the configurations.

In my project the folder conf/evolutions/default/x.sql doesn't exist so I don't have evolutions. Because of this i get a null pointer exception each time I try to access a database table.

If you need this is the **build.sbt** file:

```
name := """WebInterface"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  evolutions
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Can someone help me? I would like to know if a shell command exists to force the generation of sql files or if I have to edit some configuration files to generate these file automatically.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.sbt` you have enabled the `PlayEbean` plugin. That is correct. But you also have to add it in your `project/plugins.sbt`.

So **project/plugins.sbt** should contain this line:
`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")`